# iOS Background Colour - Solid

Tags: ios, react-native, uikit, uicolor

I am trying to change the iOS background colour, however i believe transparency (alpha:1) seems to be having an effect and altering the intended colour.

```
In **AppDelegate.m**

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:.44f green:.41f blue:.52f alpha:1];
```

If i set Alpha to 0, i get black. With Alpha set to 1, and i get a blue/grey. 
I would like a solid colour, represented by the following HEX and/or RGB value.

```
#292C34
```

or

```
rgb(41,44,52)
```

Thanks,

Comment: What color are you trying to get? `rgb 44, 41, 52` (hex #292C34) is nearly `black`, so increase the red, green, blue to get something lighter... (eg. try 44, 215, 52 alpha 0 for green)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you set the alpha to 0 then the color is completely transparent, which is why you see black. What you want to do is get the decimal value by dividing by 255.

```
rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:(44.0f/255.0f) green:(41.0f/255.0f) blue:(52.0f/255.0f) alpha:1]
```